# Jackson JSON pretty print using annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, lagom, jackson-databind

I'm using `@JSONCreator` and `@JsonCreator` to convert a response bean to JSON in Lagom Framework. But, the JSON is not formatted. How can I pretty print the JSON using the annotations (not ObjectMapper)? Here's my sample response bean:

```
@Immutable
@JsonDeserialize
public class foo {

  private final List<Result> _result;

  private final MetadataBean _meta;

  @JsonCreator
  public foo (List<Result> _result, MetadataBean _meta) {
    this._result= _result;
    this._meta = _meta;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pretty printing is controlled by the `ObjectMapper` and [cannot be influenced by annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32431555/4822566). The Lagom documentation for [negotiated serializers](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/java/MessageSerializers.html#negotiated-serializers) has this example:

```
public class JsonTextSerializer implements MessageSerializer.NegotiatedSerializer<String, ByteString> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public MessageProtocol protocol() {
        return new MessageProtocol(Optional.of("application/json"), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    }

    @Override
    public ByteString serialize(String s) throws SerializationException {
        try {
            return ByteString.fromArray(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(s));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty printing can then be enabled on the mapper (probably in a constructor):

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```