# How to specify date format in JSON response when running a unit test with MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: json, unit-testing

I have a spring boot application that uses Swagger 2.0 to generate API and model objects from Swagger API definitions. 

I am running some of the unit tests using **MockitoJUnitRunner**. 

One of the API returns an object containing a date field.

    `@JsonProperty("departureDate")`
    `private LocalDate departureDate = null;`

I am having some problems in trying to get expected date format in JSON response in the unit test.

My test looks something like this.

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class TourApiControllerStandaloneTest {
        //mock declarations
        ...
        private JacksonTester<TourHeader> jsonTourHeader;
        // controller under test
        private TourApiController tourApiController;
        private TourleaderMockData tourleaderMockData;
        ...
        @Before
        public void setup() {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(new LocalDateModule()); //LocalDateModule formats the date in yyyy-mm-dd format

            tourApiController = new TourApiController(objectMapper, 
                            httpServletRequestMock, tourServiceMock);

            JacksonTester.initFields(this, objectMapper);

            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(tourApiController)
                        .setControllerAdvice(new GlobalExceptionHandler())
                        .build();

            tourleaderMockData = new TourleaderMockData();
        }

        @Test
        public void getTourHeaderWhenExists() throws Exception {
            ...
            // given 
            given(tourServiceMock.getTourHeader(tourNumber))
                .willReturn(tourleaderMockData.getMockTourHeaderRecord(tourNumber));

            // when
            MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/tour/" + tourNumber + "/header").accept(MediaType.ALL))
                    .andReturn().getResponse();

            // then
            assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value()); 
            //  *************** THIS ASSERTION IS FAILING ****************
            assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(
jsonTourHeader.write(tourleaderMockData.getMockTourHeaderRecord(tourNumber)).getJson()
            );
        }
    }
```

Date format returned in JSON response from API call and serlized JSON from mock header object do not match. This is how the date appears in actual and expected response.

 ** Actual **
{ ...,"departureDate":**[2018,12,1]**, ...}

 ** Expected **
{...,"departureDate": **"2018-12-01"**, ...}

The same assertion works i.e. date format is coming as expected when I am using **SpringRunner** as below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(TourApiController.class)
```

Can someone please advise what I can do to get expected date format when I am running the test with **MockitoJUnitRunner**. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer from another thread on stackoverflow 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323312/5519519

So basically I needed to create an instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and set my object mapper into this instance.

And then pass this message converter at the time of setting up mockMvc.

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new
                                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(tourApiController)
                    .setControllerAdvice(new GlobalExceptionHandler())
                    .setMessageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                    .build();
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: So I successfuly followed this advice, except I couldn't find a `new LocalDateModule()`. What I had to do was in it's place use jacksons `JavaTimeModule`, and I configured it with `javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(df));` (where `df` is the date format).