# ObjectMapper configuration from application.yml not used in tests

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Note that this is **not** the same issues as in [Customized ObjectMapper not used in test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883657/), which is about importing a programmatically configured ObjectMapper.

I want to have a single source of truth for the configuration of the ObjectMapper, and the logical place to do that is the spring `application.yml` via the `spring.jackson` properties. I can't figure out how to apply that configuration though. I'm using a simple `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` annotation on my JUnit5 tests.

I've tried `@AutoConfigureJsonTesters`, `@Import(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)`, to no avail.

Comment: Have you already configured that for you default application configuration? How does it look like? Have you used any custom profiles? Do you have any custom *application.yml* configuration file for your test runtime? Please add all the relevant parts of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autowire `ObjectMapper` in your test class  as used below

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Test
  void testCreate() throws Exception {
    User user = new Usere(“ahhi”, “abhi@gmail.com”);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/register/user")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .param("sendWelcomeMail", "true")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByName("ahhi");
    assertThat(userEntity.getEmail()).isEqualTo("abhi@gmail.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: The key is to use `@SpringBootTest(classes = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)`, then the correctly configured Jackson ObjectMapper is used. Maybe you can amend your answer.