# Spring @JsonTest does not respect Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customization bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `@JsonTest` test case which doesn't find a `@Configuration` class containing a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean, and so the test fails. I can fix this with an `@Import(...)`. Is there a way to make the `@JsonTest` find my configuration automatically, or is an `@Import` expected and the only way?

Context:

Using Spring Boot Starter Parent v. 2.5.3.

My application needs to use ISO-8601 basic formatting for timestamps, which I have configured via Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {
  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
    return builder -> {
      builder.dateFormat(new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(false));
    };
  }
}
```

I wrote a small test to confirm that the `ObjectMapper` formats dates the expected way. However, `@JsonTest` does not discover my `@Configuration` with the customizations, so the test fails unless I explicitly `@Import(ObjectMapperConfig.class)`:

```java
@JsonTest
@Import(ObjectMapperConfig.class) // This is required!
public class ObjectMapperConfigTest {

  @Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Test
  public void dateFormat() throws Exception {
    var input = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0));

    var actual = mapper.writeValueAsString(input);

    // Write all dates in ISO-8601 Basic (not extended) format.
    // Timezones should be formatted +0000 instead of +00:00
    assertEquals("\"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000\"", actual);
  }
}
```

My understanding of `@JsonTest` is that it only discovers `@JsonComponent` annotations, so it would ignore normal `@Configuration`, which means (for me) it doesn't actually test the Json serialization layer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42854277/4816074) suggests what I am doing *should* work, but that does not seem to be the case. Is using an `@Import` correct, or should I annotate my configuration otherwise? Based on the documentation, it seems inappropriate to use `@JsonComponent` instead of `@Configuration`, and the @JsonTest documentation doesn't seem to comment on my scenario. Advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below approach works for me as of Spring Boot 2.5.12:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponent;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

/**
 * This customizer is annotated with @JsonComponent and hence is used both for production and @JsonTest tests.
 * More details <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730482/spring-jsontest-does-not-respect-jackson2objectmapperbuildercustomizer-customiz">here</a>
 */
@JsonComponent
public class JacksonCustomizer implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }
}
```

As much as I personally prefer to use `@Configuration` + `@Bean`, I had to refrain to `@JsonComponent` here because `@Import` seems to be more error-prone in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same situation. This jackson config is working if you boot the application, but it not take effect if you just run test.