# Spring boot mockmvc works different and request JsonCreator

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I have simple code:

I use

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
```

Here is my DTOs:

```java
    public class CreditDto {
       public final String title;
       public final String description;
       public final Long userId;
       public final DurationDto duration;
       public final Double sum;
       public final RateType rateType;
       public final PeriodType periodType;
       @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
       public final LocalDate startDate;

       public CreditDto(final String title,
                     final String description,
                     final Long userId,
                     final DurationDto duration,
                     Double sum,
                     final RateType rateType,
                     final PeriodType periodType,
                     final LocalDate startDate) {
           this.title = title;
           this.description = description;
           this.userId = userId;
           this.duration = duration;
           this.sum = sum;
           this.rateType = rateType;
           this.periodType = periodType;
           this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    
    public class DurationDto {
       public final int days;
       public final int months;
       public final int years;

       public DurationDto(int days,
                          int months,
                          int years) {
           this.days = days;
           this.months = months;
           this.years = years;
       }
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/credit/",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public class CreditController {
       private final CreditService creditService;

       public CreditController(final CreditService creditService) {
           this.creditService = creditService;
       }

       @PostMapping
       public void addCredit(final @Valid @RequestBody CreditDto credit) {
           creditService.addCredit(credit);
       }
    }
```

I run my application, post json by using Postman and everything works perfectly.

Then I have a mockMvc test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CreditControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CreditController creditController;
    @Mock
    private CreditService creditService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(creditController)
                .build();
    }

    public void addCredit() throws Exception {
    //        Given
        String content = "{"title": "MonthlyFixedCredit", "description": "My awesome second daily floating credit", "userId": 125, "duration": {"days": 0, "months": 5, "years": 0}, "sum": 10000, "startDate": "2022-09-09", "rateType": "FIXED", "periodType": "MONTHLY"}";
        doNothing().when(creditService).addCredit(any(CreditDto.class));
    //        When
        final ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/credit/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(content));
    //        Then
        result.andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(creditService, times(1)).addCredit(any(CreditDto.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(creditService);
    }
}
```

And this test failed with:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition 
error: [simple type, class org.superbank.credit.dto.CreditDto]; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.superbank.credit.dto.CreditDto` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.superbank.credit.dto.CreditDto]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.superbank.credit.dto.CreditDto` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at app//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
.........
```

Could someone help me to understand why actual application works fine without '@JsonCreator' or default constructor but I need to add it for mockMvc. I believed that mockMvc should work in the same way as actual spring mvc and do not need additional configuration just for unit test.

How can I make mockMvc behave the same way as actual mvc, what configuration I missed?

Comment: How do you configure the test class, did you follow https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ ?

Comment: I've updated listing. I'm not using @SpringBootTest but I use mockMvc

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging, the different in behaviour is due to:

[`JacksonAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html) is not loaded when using `standaloneSetup`.

> auto-registration for all Module beans with all ObjectMapper beans (including the defaulted ones).

One of those module is `ParameterNamesModule`. This module add functionality from `ParameterNamesAnnotationIntrospector` to ObjectMapper,

> Introspector that uses parameter name information provided by the Java Reflection API additions in Java 8 to determine the parameter name for methods and constructors.

that's why you can deserialize json to `CreditDto`(which does not contain default constructor) when running the application.

### Solution

1. Refer to [gigi2's answer in Customized ObjectMapper not used in test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323312/7928721), add `ParameterNamesModule` to ObjectMapper

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule()));
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(creditController).setMessageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                .build();
    }
```

This is an easy fix for this case, but you may later face another error due to other Spring magic.

2. Use `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`.
   This make sure your test environment is close to your running application. But the downside is the test run slower.